# Is it possible to use Intent to update a value in another activity?

Tags: android

I want to pass a value from one Activity to another to update an integer.  So basically I want Activity2 to send Activity1 a value it has garnered from user input.  Seems like it should be simple just not sure how.  Is it possible to run a function from another Activity and give it this value as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `Activity1` use `startActivityForResult()` to start up `Activity2`. Have `Activity2` call `setResult()` before `finish()`-ing. Have `Activity1` override `onActivityResult()` to get the result.